# Android how to get XML output of Instrumented Tests

Tags: android, xml, gradle, junit, instrumented-test

For the CI testing of my Android App I wrote some unit tests and let them run via gradle from the terminal. They all produce the typical junit XML output files in the *build/test-results* folder like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite name="my.App.Here" tests="123" skipped="0" failures="0" errors="0" ...>
 <testcase name="testABC" classname="..." time="..."/>
```

And this is what I need. However, some tests have to be instrumented tests and when I run the tests (e.g. via `./gradlew :core:connectedCheck` ) I only get human readable output.

These files are also in a different folder in *build/reports/androidTests/connected* and contain of html and css files. However no machine readable XML file is in sight.

I found some third party scripts and tools but I was hoping for a simple configuration of my gradle file or something similar.

Any ideas on **how can I get the XML output of Instrumented Tests?**

Answer (score 0):

The XML report for instrumented tests is located in `<path_to_your_project>/<module_name>/build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/`.

See the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line) for a list of all test report locations.